# 404 errors when attempting to navigate Glimpse path with MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, glimpse

Is anyone using Glimpse in an MVC6 project?  I tried using the nuget package for MVC5, but continually get `404` errors when attempting to navigate to `localhost:333/glimpse.axd.`

Is MVC6 just not supported with glimpse yet, or are others using it successfully and I have something set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, the [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/Status?milestone=vNext/) website has the following NOTE:

> vNext has started but we don't have anything to show just yet. Check
>   back soon!

Comment: Unfortunately, I assumed that would be the answer.  Thanks

Comment: I agree, this is unfortunate. But they have been working on this since October 2014.
http://blog.getglimpse.com/2014/10/03/we-need-your-help-glimpse-vnext-is-coming/

Comment: That is certainly encouraging.  Hopefully they received some great feedback.  Thanks for providing this info!

Comment: the glimpse team joined microsoft http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/07/14/the-glimpse-team-joins-microsoft.aspx from what I understand they are hoping to have something ready for asp.net 5 by the time it is officially released.